# Why is the iOS keyboard not shown when calling focus() on a textarea element in a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I place a readonly `textarea` and `button` elements on the page and when clicking the button I just remove the `readonly` attribute from the `textarea` and call `focus()` on it, but when I put this code in a `setTimeout()` it doesn't seem to work.

I just want to know why the keyboard on iOS not shown when clicking the button. Are there any solutions?

The code is in a React function compoment demo.

```js
const ref = useRef();
const handleClick = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.removeAttribute('readonly');
      ref.current.focus();
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<textarea readOnly ref={ref} />
<button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
```